# PHP Pear package not installing on IIS10

Tags: php, pear, iis-10

I downloaded https://pear.php.net/go-pear.phar accordingly and placed it to

```
c:/Program Files (x86)/PHP/v5.3/
```

And went in to CMD with admin rights, proceeded to the above directory and key'ed in

```
php go-pear.phar
```

Then I initiated a system wide installation and only did the following

[installation log screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0rSva.png)

And it failed to do the following:

- Confirm the installation
- pear command is unrecognized when running it on CMD

My system is Windows Server 2012 running IIS10, and using PHP v5.3.

Any suggestion will be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Windows Server 2012 ships with IIS 8, not IIS 10.

Answer (score 0):

The Pear command only works after we add the installation path to your Path environment.

> Either do this manually (Start > Control Panel > System >
> Environment) or run (double-click) the newly generated PEAR_ENV.reg
> that's now found in the PHP source directory.

Then we can run the command Pear in a Windows Command  Prompt.
Here is the official manual of installing the PEAR package manager in Windows.
https://pear.php.net/manual/en/installation.getting.php
If it doesn’t work yet, I suggest you install some other newer PHP version, such as PHP 5.8, afterward we execute the PEAR installation.
Feel free to let me know if there is anything